# Dynamically join multiple datasets in a dplyr/purrr workflow

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have two lists of two different years with multiple dataframes:

```
df_18 <- results_2018[[1]] %>%
        select(Answers, Austria)

df_19 <- results_2019[[1]] %>%
    select(Answers, Austria)
```

They look pretty similar, like this:

```
structure(list(Answers = c("45 to 54", "25 to 34", "35 to 44", 
"55 to 64", "16 to 24"), Austria = c(23.3, 21.5, 20.8, 15.6, 
18.8)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(Answers = c("45 to 54", "35 to 44", "25 to 34", 
"16 to 24", "55 to 64"), Austria = c(23.4, 20.7, 21.4, 18.7, 
15.8)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to make a full join on the "Answer" category for every element in both lists.

It should look like this, but for every dataset in the list and the result should also be a list of dataframes.

This is my Code for one element of each year:

```
dplyr::full_join(df_18, df_19, by="Answers") %>%
    mutate(Difference = Austria.y - Austria.x) %>%
    rename_at(vars(contains(".x")), ~str_replace(.x, ".x", "_2018")) %>%
    rename_at(vars(contains(".y")), ~str_replace(.x, ".y", "_2019")) %>%
    set_names(c("Answers", "Austria_2018", "Austria_2019", "Difference"))
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: yes the same columns for each element. Always a Year comparison for one Austria in that case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are doing this for corresponding elements of the two `list`s, use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
map2(results_2018, results_2019, ~ 
              full_join(.x %>% select(Answers, Austria),
                                 .y %>% select(Answers, Austria),
                         by = "Answers") %>%
                mutate(Difference = Austria.y - Austria.x) %>%
               rename_at(vars(contains(".x")),
                      ~str_replace(., ".x", "_2018")) %>%
               rename_at(vars(contains(".y")),
                     ~str_replace(., ".y", "_2019")) %>%
               set_names(c("Answers", "Austria_2018", "Austria_2019", "Difference")))
```

Comment: the code you postet before the edit worked, this one gives me `Error in is_closure(x) : object 'Answers' not found`

Comment: @DataMastery Sorry, my mistake.  I was thinking about `select` and didn't see `set_names`

Comment: thank you, works perfectly now. Insane how quick you came up with that solution.